# How to get the results of both tables in a join or include in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables as per the diagram.

I want to write a query that will give me the all the users with their associated relationships. The userid in the Relationship table is now `user_id`

I have tried

```
 Relationship.includes(:User)
```

but this just gives me the results of the Relationship table, as well as

```
Relationship.joins(:User)
```

which does the same

[image]

There are records in both tables and as you can see from the railroady diagram the associations are correctly set up. What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: have you tried this `User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.userid")`

Comment: I believe what you're asking for is one result-set with columns from both tables, correct?   I faced the same challenge the other day but was unable to find a good solution without resorting to plain-old SQL.   I'm eagerly monitoring this thread to see if you get a good response.

Comment: @Amit Sharma this only gives me the User table whereas as Agazoom says, Im trying to get both

Comment: try this `User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.userid").select("users.id, users.name, relationships.useeid, relationships.followsid")`

Comment: if you want to retrive all the columns from both the table then use `select("users.*, relationships.*")`

Comment: @Amit Sharma . Thats the answer apart from the typo of useeid. Can you add as an answer and then I can accept it. Thanks it worked a treat. Next step- how to convert to json!

Comment: @Sebastian Zeki,  added the answer please accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.userid").select("users.id, users.name, relationships.useeid, relationships.followsid")
```

**OR**

```
User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.userid").select("users.*, relationships.*")
```

To convert the result into json you can try following.

```
result = User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.userid").select("users.*, relationships.*")

result = result.to_json
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the diagram, you should use associations as follows:

User.rb

```
has_many :relationships
```

Relationship.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

You can access it by using

```
User.eager_load(:relationships ).select('users.* , relationships.*')
```

It will select records from both the table.

Comment: this gives me a new prompt but with single quote and no records

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eager load users with their realtionships, you can use something like:

## user.rb

```
has_many :relationships
```

## relationship.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

How to use it.

```
User.includes(:relationships)
```

## edit

as @user123 suggested you can force the eager loading by

```
User.eager_load(:relationships)
```

Comment: Im currently running this in the rails console. When I run User.includes(:relationship) and User.includes(:relationships) I get the SQL SELECT "users".* FROM "users" but it tells me that ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError: Association named 'relationship' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: What's the association between `User` and `Relationship` models?

Comment: userid is the foreign key

Comment: Have you put `has_many :relationships` into the `user` `model`, without it won't work.

Comment: I have it as has_many :Relationship. Am I using the wrong naming conventions?

Comment: Please check the edit of the answer, I added how you would declare the associations.

Comment: done as suggested but the resulting SQL is interpreted as SELECT "users".* FROM "users" so I still only get the User table output       User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  Relationship Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships"  WHERE "relationships"."user_id"

Comment: This will result two queries: One to load `users`, and another to load their `relationships`.